# How should I use external component module that does not include @type in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I added an external component module that does not include @type.
I modified a sample to like this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table

```
const StickyTable = require("react-sticky-table");
const Row = require("react-sticky-table");
const Cell = require("react-sticky-table");

export const BasicExample = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Paper>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "400px" }}>
          <StickyTable>
            <Row>
              <Cell>Header 1</Cell>
              <Cell>Header 2</Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Cell>Cell 1</Cell>
              <Cell>Cell 2</Cell>
            </Row>
          </StickyTable>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

but
any type is not be recognised "JFX.element" 
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just run your code and looks like it's not a problem with a TypeSctipt but with your imports. What you have is this:

```
const StickyTable = require("react-sticky-table");
const Row = require("react-sticky-table");
const Cell = require("react-sticky-table");
```

But from what I see in the library documentation is that a partial import should be used here. Try modifying your code to that form. It worked in my code so hopefully will be fine in your as well.

```
const StickyTable = require("react-sticky-table").StickyTable;
const Row = require("react-sticky-table").Row;
const Cell = require("react-sticky-table").Cell;
```